# Using Variables with getElementById. Trying to create chord diagrams for guitar

Tags: getelementbyid

I'm doing a little experiment that might grow into something bigger, but I've hit a snag.  Something isn't working right with the variable "placement" and getElementById.  I know you can use variables with getElementById, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  Here's my code so far.  Thanks for the help!

```
<script>

    var chord = [3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3];

    for(i=0; i<chord.length; i++){
        switch(chord[i]){
            case 0: 
                var note = '0';
            break;
            case 1: 
                var note = '1';
            break;
            case 2: 
                var note = '2';
            break;
            case 3: 
                var note = '3';
            break;
            case 4: 
                var note = '4';
            break;
            case 5: 
                var note = '5';
            break;
        }
        var placement = 'note' + i + note;
        var placement = placement.toString();
        document.getElementById(placement).innerHTML = 'o';
    }

</script>

<table class="chord">
    <tr style="border-top:5px solid gray;">
        <td id="note00"></td><td id="note10"></td><td id="note20"></td><td id="note30"></td><td id="note40"></td><td id="note50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="note01"></td><td id="note11"></td><td id="note21"></td><td id="note31"></td><td id="note41"></td><td id="note51"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="note02"></td><td id="note12"></td><td id="note22"></td><td id="note32"></td><td id="note42"></td><td id="note52"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="note03"></td><td id="note13"></td><td id="note23"></td><td id="note33"></td><td id="note43"></td><td id="note53"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="note04"></td><td id="note14"></td><td id="note24"></td><td id="note34"></td><td id="note44"></td><td id="note54"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is the value of placement, is it what you'd expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L59s4924/

it works.
But try to remove second "var" on "placement" variable declaration.

```
var placement = 'note' + i + note;
    placement = placement.toString();
```

Comment: Turns out if I put the table above the javascript it works.  It took me a bit to figure out why it was working in the jsfiddle but not on my server.  Thanks for your help.